# Execute commands on EC2 using SSM from Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to execute a list of commands on Linux EC2 instance from Lambda. My current approach is roughly as follows:

```
import boto3, time

client = boto3.client("ssm", region_name="eu-west-1")
INSTANCE_ID = "some-instance-id"

commands = ["ls -la","uname"]
response = client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID],
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
    Parameters={"commands": commands},
)
command_id = response["Command"]["CommandId"]
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    result = client.get_command_invocation(
        CommandId=command_id,
        InstanceId=INSTANCE_ID,
    )
    if result["Status"] == "InProgress":
        continue
    print(result["StandardOutputContent"])
    print(result["StandardErrorContent"])
    break
```

The downside of this is that if any command fails - it's hard to debug which one failed (cause all of them are sent in one piece), and also the `time.sleep` slow things down a bit.
I'd like to have a streaming connection to EC2, where I can send commands one-by-one and immediately receive output for each individual command, something like this:

```
commands = ["ls -la", "uname"]
for command in commands:
    output, errors = some_client.send_command(command)
    if errors:
        break
```

I tried using `SSM.Client.start_session` but it requires Session Manager plugin which is not available in AWS Lambda runtime

Comment: What errors exactly do you get? Also the code that you provided is invalid lambda function code, so its not clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have a streaming connection to EC2, where I can send commands one-by-one and immediately receive output for each individual command

You do this by starting a session with [`StartSession`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_StartSession.html) and opening a WebSocket connection to the URL it returns.

Unfortunately, the format that the connection uses is not documented other than [in the source code](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/blob/ed24864741ad3ab46385b973786633a1540fb6ec/agent/session/contracts/agentmessage.go#L62-L78), and there is no official Python library to use it (not that I know).

There are third-party libraries for the other languages around, e.g. [JS](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/aws-ssm-session).

> I tried using SSM.Client.start_session but it requires Session Manager plugin which is not available in AWS Lambda runtime

`start_session` the API call does not require the plugin.

The plugin enables CLI to connect to the session and forward the commands between the WebSocket connections and your terminal, and it's only good for the CLI, not for programmatic access.